# Prove that $LL^T$ is PD

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

Given a matrix L which is a lower triangular matrix with n raws and n columns, how may I prove that the following matrix is Positive Definite:

$$LL^T$$

In other words, I need to prove that for each $x!=0$, $$x^TLL^Tx>0$$

Comment: False when $L$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: Forgot to mention, L is lower triangular matrix

Answer (score 0):

This is true only for non-singular matrices. $x^{T}LL^{T}x=\|Lx\|^{2}$. So the statement $x^{T}LL^{T}x>0$ whenever $x \neq 0$ is true iff $Lx=0$ implies $x=0$ iff $L$ is non-singular.

Comment: "So the statement...  is true iff =0" That's not true. I think it should be true when LX!=0

Comment: So are you saying what I wrote above is true for all L != 0?

Comment: I don't understand, if I want that $x^TLL^Tx>0$ I need that $||Lx||^2>0$ which is true for all $Lx != 0$ thus for every $L!=0$. You probably have a contradiction after whenever

Comment: But what is exactly wrong with what I wrote (at which point)?

Comment: Let me clarify, $xTLL^Tx=||Lx||^2$ So when asking for $xTLL^Tx>0$ it's equal to ask that $||Lx||>0$ which is true for every Lx different than zero...

Comment: So when is $LX !=0$ when x isn't zero, it's when L is non singular, which contradicts what you wrote...

Comment: In your solution =0 should be !=0